# How to install PHP in 18.04 clean?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, php

I want to see where PHP is, because I've found it in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini., And it's not there.
I do not know which is the best way to install it, since I never did it, and I did not want to put it in the wrong place, that is why I come to you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using php5 in 18.04 then you won't be able to do it via

```
apt-get install php
```

since that installs php 7.2. If you're fine with that, then you're set. If you require php 5.6, you'll have to use ondrej/php repo which is outside of a default ubuntu repo. You can do that by adding the ppa:ondrej/php repo and then install php5.6. It should look something like this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

If you're suspecting php already is installed on the server, then you can do a few things to figure that out. This will show you what version is installed.

```
php --version
```

If you get a command not found, then chances are it is not installed. If it comes back with a version and you want to see where the bin is then you can run this to find it

```
which php
```

and that will give you the path to the file it's using. If you need to find if it's installed via apt (standard way to install)

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep php
```

and that will list all packages installed with php in their name.

Comment: Please note. From Dec 31st, `PHP 5.6` [will not receive any security fixes](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). Using it will pose a severe risk. I would not recommend installing it to start new projects, and you should start now migrating old projects.

Comment: Good catch @RoVo. I just saw in their example it was specifically utilizing the php5 instance in apache, so I wanted to include a solution in case that was a requirement on their end. Definitely want to consider migrating off that if it's still a requirement.

Comment: Thanks @SteamerJ, when executing: `sudo apt list --installed | grep php`
Returns: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
That wants to say, what should I do with the installation as you show me in your answer? Do I install 5.6 or directly `sudo apt-get install php` ?

Comment: That warning is fine, but if you didn't get any output of packages after the warning, php is not installed. 

Do you know what version of PHP you need? As @RoVo mentioned, you should avoid 5.6 unless you have a specific requirement for it as it is old and will be unsupported by end of this year. If you don't have a requirement on PHP version then just the
`sudo apt-get install php`
will suffice. You will probably need to also install the libapache2-mod-php package for the easiest setup of PHP in Apache. 
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: Thanks @SteamerJ, that I must install first,  `sudo apt-get install php` , or first `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php` ?? I do not need anything in particular, just that editing WordPress files in Visual Studio told me that it lacked PHP.

Comment: You can do them all at once `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php`